# Spring - find all where difference between start date and today is bigger than 30 days (month)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-repositories

Is it possible to write CrudRepository method without using @Query annotation which  returns all data where start date is bigger than 30 days compared to today's day?

My model contains 3 attributes: Device_id, Notification_id and created_on

also in addition I would like distinct datas by device_id

**FOR EXAMPLE**

if I have stored in my db results like this:

| dev_id | not_id | created_on |

|    1   |   1    | 2018-12-01 |

|    1   |   2    | 2018-25-07 |

|    2   |   2    | 2018-25-07 |

|    1   |   3    | 2018-16-12 |

|    2   |   3    | 2018-16-12 |

Result of data should be first 3 rows because created on is grater than 30 days compared on today date

And after that I would also want to dinstict data by device id, so I can get all device id's where created on date is bigger than month

So, I am looking for best solution for this query

Comment: Depends - whose today? Your database's today? Your application's today? Your user's browser's today?

Comment: findByCreatedOnLessThanOrCreatedOnGreaterThan(LocalDate thirtyDaysBeforeToday, LocalDate thirtyDaysAfterToday)

Comment: According to your requirement, I think you need to write query with @Query !

Answer (score 0):

ok, it's hard to implement without @Query annotation

so if someone searching for similar solutions here is my Query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT table.device_id, table.notification_id, table.created_on FROM table WHERE table.created_on < DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY", nativeQuery = true)
List<DeviceNotification> getDeviceIdWithNotificationOlderThan30Days();
```

Comment: So this is "your database's today" in my above question. Which may be want you want, but may be completely wrong. Who sets `created_on`? Is it a `TIMESTAMP` column set by the database or is it set by the application? Imagine that the database and application have unsynchronized clocks - you now have a few millis, or even seconds, where the result is wrong.

Comment: then just use your application current time, and pass it to parameter in query.

Comment: To make this an answer worth upvoting you'd need to cover these cases, explain the problem and how to solve it.